# Add space between two variables in the phpmailer headers

Tags: php

I'm sending a form mail with php.

I need to set the "from:" to the form fields which live in the variables:
$user_name and $user_lastname.

So i tried:

```
$headers .= 'From: ' . $user_name . " " . $user_lastname . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

But then i get "unknown sender" instead of name and last name.

Comment: if im not wrong, u have to add the "from" header like so: [FirstName LastName <email@domain.tld>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$headers .= 'From: "'.$user_name." ".$user_lastname.'"<'.$user_email.'>'."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're simply using the wrong (").

Try this:

```
$headers .= 'From: '. $user_name .' '. $user_lastname;
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Let me know if it isn't working

Comment: '\r\n' will output: \r\n but "\r\n" is the carriage return following by a new line